# Docker inter container communication not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Hi I am new to docker I have created docker images  and able to start them using docker compose.
Able to access these services from browser using docker tcp IP and they can ping each other using ping command.
When I tried to access the service from one another using service name in docker compose it is not accessible.
Is it a firewall issue?But both the services can be accessible from browser.

Tried by creating network when I try to inspect network both containers are in same network and they can ping each other.

These are my docker files

**backendservice**

    `FROM java:8
    EXPOSE 8080
    ADD /target/microService.jar microService.jar
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","microService.jar"]`

**uiservice**

    `FROM java:8
    EXPOSE 8081
    ADD /target/csuiservice.war csuiservice.war
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","csuiservice.war"]`

Using spring boot to develop above services and they able to access independently on exposed ports

**docker-compose.yml**

    `version: '3'
    services:
      backendservice:
        build: 
          ./BAService
        volumes:
          - ./BAService:/usr/src/app
        ports:
          - 5001:8080
      website:
        image: uiservice
        ports:
          - 5000:8081
        links:
          - "backendservice:backendservice"
        volumes:
          - ./spring-boot-web-jsp:/usr/src/app1
        depends_on:
          - backendservice
    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: mynetwork`

I am trying to access the backendservice by following url
"http://backendservice:8080/getUsers"

Comment: Can you please show us the docker-compose file? Or at least a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Make sure your apps bind to the correct interface, not to the localhost

Comment: I am calling the service by service name provided in docker compose file instead of local host.
From  uiservice using the following  Url to call backendservice.
http://backendservice:8080/getUsers

Comment: How is "mynetwork" created?

Comment: Any reason why "links" is used instead of specifying both service in same network? "links" is legacy, better to place services in same network to connect. I assume "mynetwork" is created separately and you want both service in same default "mynetwork"?

Comment: Containers are in same network i tried to inspect network.

Comment: which network are they part of? better to use user-defined bridge network rather than default bridge since service discovery is very primitive in default bridge.

Comment: They are part of my custom network "mynetwork",created by using   docker network create mynetwork                               command